# Updating existing column in Rails table to be foreign key to another table

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, foreign-keys, rails-migrations

I have an existing table in rails called `Users`. It has a column called `gender`. I have another table called `GenderOptions`. I want to create a migration so that the `gender` column in the `Users` table is a foreign key referencing the `GenderOptions` table.

the first attempt migration file looks like this:

```
class ForeignKey < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.1]
  def change
    add_reference :users, :gender, foreign_key: {to_table: :GenderOptions}
  end
end
```

But I get an error message:

```
 add_reference(:users, :gender, {:foreign_key=>{:to_table=>:GenderOptions}})
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled: (StandardError)

Mysql2::Error: Duplicate column name 'gender_id'
...:in `change'

Caused by:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Duplicate column name 'gender_id' (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)
...:in `change'

Caused by:
Mysql2::Error: Duplicate column name 'gender_id' (Mysql2::Error)
...:in `change'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I also tried:

```
class ForeignKey < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.1]
  def change
    add_foreign_key :users, :GenderOptions, column: :gender_id, primary_key: :id

  end
end
```

But I get the same error.

In Rails, how would do I update **an existing column** in an existing table to make it a foreign key referencing another table?

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression where you don't get what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & a [mre]--then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

Comment: Evidently the existing table has a column called `gender_id` (as well as/instead of the one called `gender` that you reference in your question). You'll need to use a different name for your new fkey column.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else has the same problem, the workaround solution I use was to make the changes in Workbench with SQL instead of through Rails migration:

1. Make sure all values for the attribute are set to `NULL` and make sure the data type for the reference attribute primary key and the attribute foreign key are the same (BIGINT)
2. Run `alter table users add constraint gender_forkey foreign key (gender) references genderoptions (id)`
3. In command line for Rails project run `rake db:schema:dump`